# custom action handler for UIDocumentInteractionController buttons - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7, ios7.1

Can I add custom action handler for UIDocumentInteractionController buttons?
I mean custom action handler for Facebook button, Twitter button... so on.

Also, can I remove some buttons from UIDocumentInteractionController , like Message and Email ?

I found, UIDocumentInteractionController.UTI, but if I used it, onl

I'm working on iOS7

Thank you,